# Question regarding disposition of C-struct members in memory

Tags: c

My question is based on the third case presented in this page:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member/

```
// C program to illustrate 
// size of struct 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() 
{ 

    struct C { 
        // sizeof(double) = 8 
        double z; 

        // sizeof(short int) = 2 
        short int y; 
        // Padding of 2 bytes 

        // sizeof(int) = 4 
        int x; 
    }; 

    printf("Size of struct: %ld", sizeof(struct C)); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Why does it require a padding after **y**, instead of having a padding at the end (after **x**)?

I can see why it's needed on the cases 1st and 2nd, but I fail to see it on the 3rd.

Comment: Please include the relevant code directly into the question.

Comment: You don't need padding at the end; you need padding before a misaligned member to align it properly. So if the `int` needs to be or should be aligned to a 4-byte boundary, padding is used to push it to a 4-byte boundary.

Comment: What part is not clear from the explanation given on the linked page?

Comment: @ikegami does that 4-byte thing varies on 32-bit or 64-bit architectures?

Comment: The required/used padding can vary by compiler and based on what system is targeted. But I believe it's generally sufficient for something of size N to be at an address evenly divisible by N, so 32- vs 64-bit wouldn't normally matter.

Comment: Keep in mind the size of an `int` can vary by compiler and based on what system is targeted. C only guarantees that an `int` must be able to present the integers in [−32,767, +32,767] at a minimum (which only requires 16 bits). Larger is allowed.

Comment: @ikegami sorry but I don't know if I'm fully understading you. Are you saying that every member of a struct must start at a position on memory that's multiple of 4?

Comment: @kaylum it's done.

Comment: @dxiv the questions is: Why does it require a padding after y, instead of having a padding at the end (after x)?

Comment: @JayJay The explanation on the linked page is "*y (short int) is followed by x (int)*" which follows the common rule stated at the top "*padding is only added when a structure member is followed by a member with a larger size or ...*". There is also a little picture to illustrate that.

Comment: Re "*Are you saying that every member of a struct **must** start at a position on memory that's multiple of **4**?*", (Emphasis mine) No, I said a compiler **may decide** to place the members at an address that's a multiple of **their size**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some computer architectures, instructions that access values in memory will only accept a subset of all addresses due to *alignment restrictions*. For example, an instruction that copies a 32-bit value from memory into a register might require the value to be at an address that's divisible by 4. (You might still be able to obtain the value byte-by-byte, but that would far slower as it would require multiple instructions). Other architectures might merely perform better if the value are aligned properly. And in yet other architectures, it might not matter at all.

As such, the C standard allows for implementation-specific padding to be used in structures. By adding padding, the compiler can assure that each member will be properly aligned (since it can enforce an alignment on the structure itself). This allows us to declare the following and let the compiler figure out the exact size and offsets:

```
struct A { 
    int x; 
    short y; 
    double z;
};
```

---

Let's look at what a compiler *might* do.

Let's say your system uses 2 bytes for `short` values, 4 bytes for `int` values and 8 bytes for `double` values. And let's say values of size N are required to be placed at an address evenly divisible by N.

```
struct A { 
    int x;      // 4 bytes, address must be divisible by 4.
    double z;   // 8 bytes, address must be divisible by 8.
    short y;    // 2 bytes, address must be divisible by 2.
};
```

If we just put the members end to end, `z` would be found at offset 4, which isn't divisible by 8, so the computer would be unable to access this field efficiently. The compiler might therefore utilize padding.

```
struct A { 
    int x;      // 4 bytes, address must be divisible by 4.   // At offset  0.
                // 4 bytes of padding.                        // At offset  4.
    double z;   // 8 bytes, address must be divisible by 8.   // At offset  8.
    short y;    // 2 bytes, address must be divisible by 2.   // At offset 16.
};
```

Now, `z` is at offset 8, which is divisible by 8.

---

But that's not quite it.

The alignment restrictions are imposed on the absolute address of the members, not merely their offset. So the members of `struct C` are only properly aligned if the address of the structure itself is at an address evenly divisible by 8. The compiler can take care of that when you do

```
struct A a;
```

But what if you do

```
struct A *array = malloc(sizeof(struct A) * n);
```

`malloc` will return a pointer that meets all possible alignment restrictions, so `array[0]` will be properly aligned, but what about `array[1]`? For that to be properly aligned, `sizeof(struct A)` needs to be a multiple of 8! So padding will be added to the end to make the size of the structure a multiple of 8, and we end up with this:

```
// Address must be divisible by 8, so sizeof(struct A) must be divisible by 8.
struct A { 
    int x;      // 4 bytes, address must be divisible by 4.   // At offset  0.
                // 4 bytes of padding.                        // At offset  4.
    double z;   // 8 bytes, address must be divisible by 8.   // At offset  8.
    short y;    // 2 bytes, address must be divisible by 2.   // At offset 16.
                // 2 bytes of padding.                        // At offset 18.
};
```

---

Finally, you asked about `struct C`. Applying the above, we get:

```
// Address must be divisible by 8, so sizeof(struct C) must be divisible by 8.
struct C { 
    double z;   // 8 bytes, address must be divisible by 8.   // At offset  0.
    short y;    // 2 bytes, address must be divisible by 2.   // At offset  8.
                // 2 bytes of padding.                        // At offset 10.
    int x;      // 4 bytes, address must be divisible by 4.   // At offset 12.
                // 0 bytes of padding.                        // At offset 16.
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was asking for!

Comment: @ikegami thanks for the update. I've read it all and now it's even more clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

As described, by the site,

"C language doesn’t allow the compilers to reorder the struct members to reduce the amount of padding. In order to minimize the amount of padding, the struct members must be sorted in a descending order (similar to the case 2)."

This means that the padding for the structs are created right after they are made. C language can't reorder struct members, so the code runs like this: creates 8 bytes of storage for double z first, then creates 2 bytes of storage for short int y with a padding of 2 bytes, and finally creates 4 bytes of storage for int x. You should think of the padding as a package with the original storage: you can't separate them, which is why the padding of y is created before the storage for x is.

Edit: Sorry if my response was a little confusing or didn't answer the question. x is an int, so x doesn't have any padding. y is a **short** int, so it has the 2 byte padding. The padding doesn't at the end because it comes with the variable that requires it (y).

-mihirm

Comment: Thanks for answering but you simply copy/pasted what the page said. My question, as I stated, is why it's necessary the padding before "X" instead of leaving an space AFTER "X".